# HTML sentence running on, looking for way to wrap

Tags: html

I have a bit of text in the code below and can't figure out how wrap it...right now it just runs on and on, off the page. Would appreciate any help.

```
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<h3><span style="font-size: 22px; font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif; max-width:     900px;">Welcome!</span></h3>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<hr style="width: 900px; color: #e0e0e0;" />
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p><span style="font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;">This is the most amazingest company of all in the wide universe. The owner is super beautiful, smart and amazing in every way. Please buy our stuff or we'll have to send out our people to break your legs and that would make us feel bad.</span></p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<hr style="width: 900px; color: #777777;" />
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<hr style="width: 900px; color: #777777;" />
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<table style="width: 900px;" border="0" cellspacing="3" cellpadding="2" align="center">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td><img class="__mce_add_custom__" title="wine-small.jpg" src="http://bluebasilgifts.mybigcommerce.com/product_images/uploaded_images/wine-small.jpg" alt="wine-small.jpg" width="295" height="197" /></td>
<td><img class="__mce_add_custom__" title="shipping-small.jpg" src="http://bluebasilgifts.mybigcommerce.com/product_images/uploaded_images/shipping-small.jpg" alt="shipping-small.jpg" width="295" height="197" /></td>
<td><img class="__mce_add_custom__" title="chocolate-small.jpg" src="http://bluebasilgifts.mybigcommerce.com/product_images/uploaded_images/chocolate-small.jpg" alt="chocolate-small.jpg" width="295" height="197" /></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<hr style="width: 900px; color: #777777;" />
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<h3><span style="font-size: 22px; font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif; max-width: 900px;">Featured Products</span></h3>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<hr style="width: 900px; color: #777777;" />
<p>&nbsp;</p>
```

Comment: text wraps fine: http://jsfiddle.net/QzU7A/ Probably some other css at play here...

Comment: I concur...I've tried may things and unable to figure this out. Thanks for confirming, helps to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have a CSS rule that applies on your `span` or `p` tag that is causing this.

Try to add this CSS rule as important and see if it fixes your problem.

```
span {
    word-break: normal !important;
    word-spacing: 0px !important;
    word-wrap: normal !important;
}
```

If this fix your problem i would suggest you to drill down, find the css rule that causes that and make some changes as i wouldn't advise you to keep the above css rule with the !important.

Comment: Tried this but to no avail. It appears you as well as PeterVR above) are correct...looks like I have some investigating to do. Thanks for the help anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Figured out this was just a matter of my Wrapper and Container sizes being out of whack. Changed the dimensions and now everything lines up perfectly.